# Run Django's model makemigration from package

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I have different package's structure and i want to run makemigration and then migrate but it doesn't work. i have app **user_app** and models package where is my custom user model's file. when i run makemigration i have this - > **No changes detected in app 'user_app'**
what i can do?
it's my project structure

[image]

**user.py**

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser, BaseUserManager
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.dispatch import receiver
from rest_framework.authtoken.models import Token
from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError
from user_app.const import STATUS_CHOICES


def validate_length(value):
    if len(str(value)) != 11:
        raise ValidationError(('Passport must be 11 digit!'))


class MyUserManager(BaseUserManager):
    def create_user(self, email, last_name, first_name, passport_id, password=None):
        if not email:
            raise ValueError('Email is required')
        elif not last_name:
            raise ValueError('Last name is required')
        elif not first_name:
            raise ValueError('First name is required')
        elif not passport_id:
            raise ValueError('Passport is required')
        user = self.model(
            email=self.normalize_email(email),
            last_name=last_name,
            first_name=first_name,
            passport_id=passport_id
        )
        user.set_password(password)
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user

    def create_superuser(self, email, password):
        user = self.model(
            email=self.normalize_email(email),
        )
        user.set_password(password)
        user.is_admin = True
        user.is_staff = True
        user.is_superuser = True
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user


class User(AbstractUser):
    email = models.EmailField(unique=True, verbose_name='Email', error_messages={'unique': 'This email already exists'})
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=20, verbose_name='First name')
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=25, verbose_name='Last name')
    passport_id = models.BigIntegerField(validators=[validate_length], verbose_name='Passport')
    status = models.CharField(max_length=20, choices=STATUS_CHOICES)

    object = MyUserManager()
    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = []

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = ('User')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.email


@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def create_auth_token(sender, instance=None, created=False, **kwargs):
    if created:
        Token.objects.create(user=instance)
```

Comment: Remove your initial.py file from migrations folder and delete db and then run it.

Comment: @SunderamDubey i don't have initial.py file in migrations. now i run migrate and migration is running but there is not initial.py

Comment: Do you have any data in the database now?

Comment: @Metalgear I fixed it, problem was that i have not "from .user import User"  in __init__.py